# How to plot Gauss sums?

Tags: matlab, plot, gauss

I'm trying to plot the Gauss sums according to the equation shown in the image s(t), but I keep receiving errors.
Can you please show me what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

[image]

```
%%
Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sampling period
L = 1024;                     % Length of signal
t = 2*(0:L-1)*T;               % Time vector
x = 0;
k = 0;
s = 0;
p = primes(L);
% s(t) = cumsum((k/p)(1:length(p)-1)).*exp(1i*k*t);
for k=1:p-1
    
s(t) = s(t) + (k/p).*exp(1i*k*t);
    
end
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,s)
title('signal')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're treating the [Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) symbol as fraction - which it is not despite the deceivingly similar appearance.

Furthermore the index for your summation doesn't make a whole lot of sense, you probably just wan to use `s` as summing variable. So you just have to replace `k/p` in your summation expression with the Legendre symbol.

Comment: is there a function for the legendre symbol that I should use ? 
what do you mean by "the index for your summation doesn't make a whole lot of sense" ?

Comment: If `s` is an array you can't use non-integral indices `t`. You should just use `s` as a vector. I don't think there is a built in legendre symbol function, you're probably gonna have to write one yourself.

Comment: I edited the code a little bit and added the jacobiSymbol function, but I still keep getting errors

Comment: It seems now you have problems unrelated to your first question. Please ask a separate question and do not forget to include an [MCVE]. You shouldn't edit a post to ask a new question but creat a new post instead.